# Paypal Adaptive Payments Find Application ID

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, app-id

I received API credentials but I need an Application ID to send Adaptive Accounts API Requests.

I used their sandbox app ID: APP-80W284485P519543T.

Now it's time to go live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Adaptive Payments and Adaptive Accounts [are deprecated](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), and can no longer be used for new integrations.

Instead, PayPal will tell you to use a supported integration such as [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/).  You can find a front-end demo here:

- Version that calls server-side routes to create and capture a v2/order via APIs: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
- Version that does not do that, and instead only uses client-side HTML/JS: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client